# Curl command execution in linux - globbing error

Tags: linux, curl

I have below code which I am running on linux.
It is throwing lot of errors even though the json formatter is correct.

```
curl -o  -skd { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "addAction", "params":{"action":{"id": "Syslog","name": "Syslog Action","isSystem": false,"type": "SendSyslogMessage","arguments": [{"key": "SyslogServerName","value": "10.41.155.233"},{"key": "SyslogServerUseTcp","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerUseTls","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerNoBsdCompat","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerCaCertChain","value": ""},{"key": "SyslogServerAllowOffTimeRangeCerts","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerPort","value": "514"}]}},"id": 1}
```

Errors:-

```
Warning: The file name argument '-skd' looks like a flag.
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jsonrpc
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 2.0,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: method
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: addAction,
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 16
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Syslog,name
curl: (3) Host name 'Syslog Action,isSystem' contains bad letter
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: false,type
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SendSyslogMessage,arguments
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerName,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 14
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerUseTcp,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerUseTls,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerNoBsdCompat,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerCaCertChain,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerAllowOffTimeRangeCerts,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: SyslogServerPort,value
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 4
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 2
```

Comment: Maybe it works when you place the whole argument in single quotes: `'{ .... .... }'`.

Comment: I tried it but there is one error remaining.


Warning: The file name argument '-skd' looks like a flag.
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 53

Comment: I understand why this question was closed. I didnt formatted it properly initially and wasn't looking neat. Christian Fritz had edited this question and now it looks good to me.
The question is helpful for anyone facing this issue.
Please if the moderator or other people can again open this page.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON must be inside of single quotes, or else the shell and curl think that it is all different command line arguments to be parsed.

```
curl -o  -skd '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "addAction", "params":{"action":{"id": "Syslog","name": "Syslog Action","isSystem": false,"type": "SendSyslogMessage","arguments": [{"key": "SyslogServerName","value": "10.41.155.233"},{"key": "SyslogServerUseTcp","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerUseTls","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerNoBsdCompat","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerCaCertChain","value": ""},{"key": "SyslogServerAllowOffTimeRangeCerts","value": "0"},{"key": "SyslogServerPort","value": "514"}]}},"id": 1}'
```

Comment: I tried it but there is one error remaining.

Warning: The file name argument '-skd' looks like a flag.
curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 53

Comment: I suppose you need to write `curl -o SOMEFILE -skd ...`.